# Does soya milk decrease testosterone?

Tags: nutrition

This article: http://www.livestrong.com/article/240105-does-soy-milk-lower-testosterone/
seems to suggest that it is indecisive.
Is there concrete evidence for either side of the argument?

> Neither soy protein nor soy isoflavones had any effect on testosterone
>   levels in adult men who consumed soy foods or products

Comment: Please add a quote of the main claim from the source.

Comment: See also [Do soy beans and corn flakes decrease libido?](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/9860/2703)

Comment: [Is Soy bad for you?](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/4037/2703)

Comment: [Does eating soy affect men's virility?](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/17488/2703)

Comment: The article you reference cites what appear to be peer-reviewed published papers.  I'm not sure how someone here is going to improve on that.  There appears to be concrete evidence for *both* sides of the argument, suggesting that further studies are needed.

Comment: @NateEldredge Or, maybe no further study is needed and the question has been answered conclusively; maybe the allegedly concrete evidence on one side isn't convincing and/or can be explained away.

Comment: The linked article doesn't say that it does. It claims it's controversial. Can you show that a lot of people believe it has that effect?